# Реализация интерфейса ICollection в конструкторе класса

Tags: c#, проектирование, solid

Когда читаю различные туториалы, да и наш любимый StackOverflow, то часто вижу подобный [код](http://www.aspnetmvcninja.com/views/asp-net-mvc-select-list-example):

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public ICollection<int> CategoryID { get; set; }

        public Product()
        {
            CategoryID = new List<int>();
        }
    }
}
```

Объясните зачем свойство `CategoryID` объявлять как интерфейс `ICollection`, если в конструкторе он явно инициализируется при помощи `List`?

Что пытается избежать проектировщик при таком подходе?

Я понимаю если бы в класс `Product` внедрялась какая-то зависимость через его конструктор. Но этого ведь нет.

Какой концептуальный момент я упустил?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Значение торчит наружу и клиентский код не знает, что там `List`. То есть, по велению левой пятки архитектора, в новой версии библиотеки `List` может быть заменено на `LinkedList` и никто не пострадает. Это абстракция над реализацией коллекции.

Comment: _в новой версии библиотеки_. Под словом **библиотека** понимается класс **Product**? Если так, то при  создании новой версии `Product` все равно же весь выше написанный код продублируется, просто в место `CategoryID = new List<int>()` будет `CategoryID = new ДругаяКоллекции<int>()`. Какой смысл абстрагироваться?

Comment: @adamshakhabov, если у вас выставлен `List` и клиентский код вызывает метод `Product.CategoryId.ForEach()`, то при смене типа коллекции код сломается. А если выставлена `ICollection`, то такого кода не будет. Единственная проблема с `ICollection` может быть, если туда `Array` присвоят.

Comment: @adamshakhabov Product - это публичный тип, т.е. к нему можно обращаться из других сборок. Внутри Product не менее публичное свойство CategoryID. Чем там оно инициализируется внутри типа - это внутренние трудности Product. Вы же можете подтянуть эту сборку в виде dll. То есть вам даже не придется пересобирать свой проект (благодаря абстракции и обязательному динамическому связыванию в .NET).

Comment: @Vlad, _если у вас выставлен List и клиентский код вызывает метод Product.CategoryId.ForEach(), то при смене типа коллекции код сломается_. 1) Т.е. я как-бы изначально предотвращаю использование в клиентском коде `ForEach()`? 2) А что мне мешает изначально прописать `CategoryID = new Collection<int>()`, раз необходимо ограничится функционалом `ICollection`? Какую гибкость я теряю?

Comment: @adamshakhabov, 1) да, вы предотвращаете использование в клиентском коде методов, которые специфичны для определенных коллекций. В частности, `ForEach`. 2) Ничего не мешает. Но, например, вы в какой-то момент осознали, что вам нужно отслеживать изменения в этой коллекции. Вы можете заменить ее на `ObservableCollection` и подписаться на ее события. При этом для вызывающего кода ничего не поменяется.

Comment: На самом деле, этот тип ничего не инкапсулирует;) Тут все данные открытые, никакого поведения. Да и если в коллекцию (которая мутабельная) добрый человек запишет массив будет много веселого происходить в рантайме;)

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov Мы тут теоретизируем ;-)

Comment: Все проще: ICollection - это требование entity framwork. Добавил отдельный ответ.

Comment: Удалил второй ответ ибо был не прав.

Answer (score 5):

Здесь автор, по идее, старается следовать принципу наименьшего знания и не выставлять наружу детали реализации.

Возможно данный код старый или не показаны все составляющие, но в данной реализации дизайн не хорош.

1. Свойство `CategoryID` мутабельное.
   Клиент может записать туда `null` с последующим огребанием `NullReferenceException`.
2. Свойство только старается спрятать детали реализации, но делает это плохо.
   Все сильно зависит от контекста, но существует как минимум два способа сделать этот дизайн более жестким с одной стороны и более простым с другой.

Во-первых, можно сделать тип неизменяемым и получать коллекцию в конструкторе. В этом случае, свойство `CategoryID` вместо типа `ICollection` может стать `IReadOnlyCollection` или `IReadOnlyList`.

Во-вторых, если класс нельзя сдлать иммутабельным, то есть смысл добавить метод `AddCategory` и все же сделать свойство `CategoryID` типом `IReadOnlyCollection/IReadOnlyList`.

Тут сложно говорить без контекста, но меня всегда поражают подобные объекты-данные в пространствах имен с именем `Model`. Модель в имени пространства имен говорит мне о том, что здесь будет спрятана вся суть приложения, ее доменные объекты, с поведением и всякими наворотами. А когда я вижу в таком пространстве имен простые объекты-данные, у меня происходит некоторое несовпадение ожиданий с реальностью.

Другими словами, если есть желание создавать модели, то есть смысл прятать внутренности полноценно, а не убирая "реальный тип списка". Тогда можно будет добавлять более высокоуровневое поведение (какую-нибудь логику фильтрации по категориям и чего-нить еще) не ломая существующих клиентов.

А теперь немного по теме:

Интерфейсы коллекций в BCL немного сумасшедшие в том плане, что сейчас уже очень сложно сказать, что они означают. Это особенно относится к типу `ICollection`: что это за коллекция? Является ли она изменяемой? Вроде бы да, там же есть метод `Add`. Но вот беда, массивы тоже реализуют `ICollection<T>`, метод `Add` которых бросает исключение. Да, там есть свойство `IsReadOnly`, но точно ли все клиенты его проверят?

Ну, конечно, у коллекций есть методы `Contains` и `Remove`, но первый дает сложность O(N), что почти всегда плохо, а второй также не работает для всех коллекций.

Вот и получается, что этот интерфейс зачастую используется в качестве такого себе  `IEnumerable + Count`, но и в этом случае лучше подойдут `IReadOnlyXXX` представления.

В качестве заключения: нужно понимать что и от кого вы прячите и прячите ли вы вообще что-либо. Если данный код используется в приложения, то есть два варианта: использовать конкретную коллекцию, если класс является хранилищем данных или же прятать коллекцию полноценно и выставлять `IReadonlyXXX` представление со специализированными методами `Add`.

Comment: @downvoter: будет интересно обсудить, что не понравилось в ответе;)

Comment: такой призыв не сработает и его никто не увидит. Лучше писать на [мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/) больше шансов, что увидят и могут ответить. Я поставил минус, потому что на мой взгляд, данный ответ - это поток сознания никак не пересекающийся с вопросом.

Comment: *Извиняюсь за прошлые комментарии, немного ошибся с телепатией.*

Comment: Рекомендации в целом хорошие - но надо смотреть для чего эти классы используются. А используются они исключительно для передачи данных от контроллера к представлению. Отсюда - крайне небольшие ограничения. Фактически, контроллер работает с этими классами в режиме WriteOnly, а представление - ReadOnly.

Comment: По терминологии же - согласен. Прибить бы того, что додумался DTO называть моделями.

Comment: Не downvoter - так, мимо проходил. "Модель в имени пространства имен говорит мне о том, что здесь будет спрятана вся суть приложения, ее доменные объекты, с поведением и всякими наворотами". Почему вас не устраивают разделение на модели, которые подразумевают отражение структуры БД, и код, который этими моделями манипулирует? По поводу `ICollection` полностью согласен, но, как заметил free_ze, мы тут теоретизируем. Вопрос-то был "что пытается избежать проектировщик при таком подходе"?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: если это простой посредник между двумся слоями, то нечего стеснятся и использовать конкретные типы коллекций. Ведь инкапсуляцией здесь и не пахнет. Это ж как тройной бургер с диетической колой. Основная проблема не в типе коллекции, а в открытости данных:)

Comment: @Vlad: отражение структуры БД - это не модель предметной области. Ведь это даже не ООП вовсе. Тут есть данные, но нет поведения, а значит нет абстракции и нет инкапсуляции;)

Comment: Абстракция в виде наследования там, все же, может быть. :) но это же все равно модель (пусть и не предметной области)? Или как ее тогда называть?

Comment: Ну, я их тогда называю DTO. Data etc. Слово "модель", все же подразумевает либо процесс моделирования некоторой реальности (чего нет), либо предметной области, либо чего-то еще.
Видимо слово "модель" здесь отражает M в паттернах MVP, MVC. Там эти классы тоже обычно связаны с предметной областью.
Можно сказать, что это область столь проста, что там не нужно полноценное ООП. Но тогда, как я уже писал, нечего заморачиваться с интерфейсами.

Comment: Про интерфейсы согласен. Спасибо за разъяснения.